# How can I render my defined model in my view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller

not sure if I'm going about this the right way, but I have the following in my model and would like to render it in my view (i.e. to show the number of open student spaces left)

Model:

```
   def open_student_spots
              event.student_rsvp_limit - event.student_rsvps_count
   end
```

This is the area I am trying to display in my views and here's what I've done (albeit incorrect, so far)

```
     <i class='fa fa-user'></i>Spaces Available: <%= 
    <% if event.students_at_limit? %>
      (<%= event.student_waitlist_rsvps_count %> Waitlisted)
      <% else %>
     <%  open_student_spots %>  #how to fix this line?
  </div>
<% end %>
```

How can I make this work, please?

Comment: I have a felling that  this is wrong `event.student_rsvp_limit - event.student_rsvps_count`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
<%= event.open_student_spots %>
```

1) Use the = to denote output.

2) It's a method on the model, so you should call it on the event instance. (Which itself should perhaps be an instance variable rather than a local variable)

Answer (score 1):

You should give it like `<%= event.open_student_spots %>` to display in the view.

A small note:

```
<% %> # Executes the code.

<%= %> # Prints the output.
```

Comment: Thank you - this worked.  And I will remember that note in the future!